# Setting instance variable for controller in ApplicationController doesn't works

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created in a ApplicationController file a method, that should set a instance variable in all my actions:

```
def self.set_body_id(id)
    print "This is test"
    self.instance_variable_set(:@body_id, id)
end
```

When i call this method in another controller, like this:

```
class HostingController < ApplicationController
    set_body_id "Test"

    def index
    end
end
```

.. And nothing happens. `@body_id` variable was not available in the view. So i run a rails console to check if this function are even get executed, and as I expected, I get a `This is test` string on output, when i call a `HostingController.new`, but still `@body_id` was undefined.

Also I remove `self` from a `self.variable_instance_set` and even repleace this line with a `@body_id = "Test"`, and this still didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I see where I made a mistake. I try to set an instance variable before even creating a class instance. It's seems that the `self.set_body_id` shoud get involved a class `initialize`, but still have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You're mixing class and instance variable

Comment: @apneadiving: So, it's a any way to get this worked? I like to have a controller-wide variable that is accessible from a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery

    def self.set_body_id(id)
        self.class_variable_set(:@@body_id, id)
    end

    before_filter :set_body_attributes

    private

    def set_body_attributes
        @body_id = self.class.class_variable_get(:@@body_id)
    end
end
```

Thank you for your response, I was able to figure it out thanks to @apneadiving tip :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write it like this:

```
def set_body_id(id)
  instance_variable_set("@body_id", id)
end
```

UPDATE: I just saw that you use a class method which should be an instance method. I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    protected
      def set_body(id)
        ApplicationController.get_id(id)
      end

     def self.get_id(id)
      self.class_variable_set(:@@body, id)
      end
   end
```

Your Hosting controller

```
class HostingController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :set_body

protected

  def set_body
      @body = super(params[:id])
  end
end
```

The **@body** instance variable that i am setting from set_body should be accesible in all methods.  Try it by inspecting it